# Galaxy Nexus won't charge, will immediately reboot if turned off

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, charging

Ran into a bizarre problem this morning.  My Galaxy Nexus was plugged in, but not charging.  Data transfer over USB seemed to work, but no charging would happen.  Stranger still, if I turned the phone off, it would immediately start booting up.  I couldn't actually get it to be off.

I couldn't find these symptoms on google, so I'm posting here.  I did eventually solve it by pulling out the battery and putting in a different one (the lower capacity one the phone came with).  It seemed to be normal, and continues to be normal after I switched back to the battery which wasn't charging earlier.  Anyone know the actual cause?  Either way, a solution is here for distressed users.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Thanks for sharing your experience. Would you mind copying your solution to an answer? Having it in the question alone makes the post appear like an issue without solution in lists. Thanks again, and enjoy your stay here!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing the battery and putting it back in solves the problem, at least temporarily.  A few days later, I found the same problem was happening, and the same solution worked.